# D3js Tree graph become unresponsive after adding linebreak and custom transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I m having trouble to add line break to this functionality. The base code for this is taken from this [SITE](http://jsfiddle.net/syedbilal/Lrywwb2L/). I have also added entering transition using breadth first style with the function called "autoOpen". Initially, I have implemented the line break shown in this [SITE 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447321/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-in-javascript). It was working fine until I implemented the "autoOpen" functionality. When I implement both the function, the tree would become unresponsive. Is there any way I can implement both the function?
Thank you

EDIT : I took the entering transition from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834304/d3js-collapsible-tree-entering-transition-using-depth-first-style)

```
 function buildTree(treeData){
  var margin = {top:40, right:120,bottom:20,left:20};
  var width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left;
  var height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var i = 0,duration = 750;
    //refers to the tree itself
  var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height,width])
    .nodeSize([100,100]);

  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d){
      return [d.x, d.y];
    });

  //refers to the rectangle outside
  var zm;
  var svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
    .attr("width",width+margin.right+margin.left)
    .attr("height",height+margin.top+margin.bottom)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")")
    .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5,2]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+400+","+50+")");

  zm.translate([400,20]);

  var root = treeData;

  update(root);

  autoOpen(root,1000);

  function update(source){
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

    nodes.forEach(function(d){
      d.y = d.depth * 100;
    });

    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes,function(d){
        return d.id || (d.id = ++ i);
      });

    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class","node")
      .attr("transform",function(d){
        if(!source.x0 && !source.y0)
          return "";
        return "translate("+source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
      })
      .on("click",nodeClick)
      .on('contextmenu', d3.contextMenu(contextMenuList));

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r",40)
      .attr("stroke",function(d){
        return d.children || d._children ? "steelblue" : "steelblue";
      })
      .style("fill",function(d){
        return d.children || d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      })

    nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("y",function(d){
        //return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18;
        return 0;
      })
      .attr("dy",".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor","middle")
      .text(function(d){
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill-opacity",1e-6);

    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform",function(d){
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r",40)
      .style("fill",function(d){
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity",1);

    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform",function(d){
        return "translate("+ source.x+","+source.y+")";
      })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r",1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity",1e-6);


    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links,function(d){
        return d.target.id;
      });

    link.enter().insert("svg:path","g")
      .attr("class","link")
      .attr("d",function(d){
        if(!source.x0 && !source.y0)
          return "";
        var o = {x:source.x0,y:source.y0};
        return diagonal({source:o,target:o});
      });

    link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d",diagonal);

    link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d",function(d){
        var o = {x:source.x,y:source.y};
        return diagonal({source:o,target:o});
      })
      .remove();

    nodes.forEach(function(d){
      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.y0 = d.y;
    });
  }

  function nodeClick(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
  }

  function redraw() {
    svg.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
      + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  }

  function autoOpen(head,time){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      nodeClick(head);
      if(head.children){
        var timeOut = 1000;
        head.children.forEach(function(child){
          autoOpen(child,timeOut);
          timeOut = timeOut + 1000;
        })
      }
    },time);
  }
}

buildTree(treeData);
```

Comment: what do you mean by unresponsive? what are you seeing?

Comment: @KWeiss only the root node is shown and doesn't show anything if clicked on it.

Comment: any errors in the console?